# How to call an method which resides in different project?

Tags: java

I have Two separate projects in eclipse work space is same but different two projects.
Suppose two project A & B, i have call an class suppose `Test.java` having main method and one simple display method from project b and i need to call from project B.In main method i am calling display method of Test.java class.

And suppose i have another class `Execute.java` in project A so i need call class from Project B in to Project A in `Execute.java` class, how do i do that?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

File : TestNGCreator.java

```
package testDrivers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import projlib.Globals;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;




public class TestNGCreator 
{

    public void runTestNGTest() throws IOException 
    {

            //Create an instance on TestNG
            TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

            //Create an instance of XML Suite and assign a name for it.
            XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();
            mySuite.setName(Globals.SUITE_NAME);

            //Create a list of XmlTests and add the Xmltest you created earlier to it.
            List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();

            XSSFSheet excelWSheet = null;
            XSSFWorkbook excelWBook = null;
            XSSFCell cell = null;
            XSSFRow row = null;

            Double dblCellVal;
            String strCellVal = null;
            Boolean blnCellVal;

            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(Globals.CONFIG_FILE_DIR);
            excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            //excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(Globals.CONFIG_SHEET_NAME);


            Iterator <Row> rowIterator = excelWSheet.iterator(); 
            //Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            String testName = null;
            int colCount;

            if (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                colCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            }
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int curCell = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
                    curCell++;
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        dblCellVal = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        strCellVal = dblCellVal.toString();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        strCellVal = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        blnCellVal = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        strCellVal = blnCellVal.toString();
                        break;
                    }

                    //If it is first cell then store the Test Name
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex()== 0)
                    {
                        testName = strCellVal;
                    }

                    if (curCell == 5) {
                        if (strCellVal.equals("1.0")) {
                            //Adding to suite
                            //Create an instance of XmlTest and assign a name for it.
                            XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);
                            myTest.setName(testName);

                            //Add any parameters that you want to set to the Test.
                            Map<String, String> testngParams = new HashMap<String,String> ();
                            testngParams.put("testId", testName);
                            myTest.setParameters(testngParams);

                            //Create a list which can contain the classes that you want to run.
                            List<XmlClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass> ();
                            myClasses.add(new XmlClass("TestDriver"));

                            //Assign that to the XmlTest Object created earlier.
                            myTest.setXmlClasses(myClasses);

                            //Adding the test to test list created earlier
                            myTests.add(myTest);
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            excelWBook.close();

            //add the list of tests to your Suite.
            mySuite.setTests(myTests);

            //Add the suite to the list of suites.
            List<XmlSuite> mySuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
            mySuites.add(mySuite);

            //Set the list of Suites to the testNG object you created earlier.
            myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);

            File file = new File(Globals.TESTNG_FILE_NAME);
            System.out.println("File is: " + file);

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(mySuite.toXml());
            writer.close();

            //invoke run() - this will run your class.
            //myTestNG.run();




    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        TestNGCreator testDriver = new TestNGCreator();
        testDriver.runTestNGTest();
    }
}
```

So i need to call main method.

Comment: import the other project as a dependency and call it. Or call it through a rest or soap call ..

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: No actually i need to run the automation that i have developed and for that i need to call automation using web service by passing the parameters like Excel file,sheetname and testcaseid like that to an method which resides in Automation project for WebService Project hence i ask that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by following below steps.

1. Build the first project and create jar
2. Right click on second project ->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jars
3. Use the class from first project

**Or**

If you want to send/receive data from any web service, Please expose your method as REST API such a way that your web service will accept it.

You can use Apache HttpComponents to expose your method to web service, Please find the below sample code.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                    .disableContentCompression().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
client.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: Please see the above comment if that possible or not depends please update the answer if the answer will be different

Comment: @akshaypatil I added hint for it, Please try to use that

Comment: I am getting error as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testDrivers.TestNGCreator where testDrivers is package and TestNGCreator is an class that i am calling from another project

Comment: @akshaypatil, You don't need class name. you only need complete url of the api and inside api handler on webserver you have to call your method.

Comment: but the class contains my main method i will add in question look wait..

Comment: We can also call methods without main methods. Please write proper server program and deploy it on server like tomcat and try to hit url, Once url handler is invoked at your server will call your method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Maven or Gradle you can perform the following steps in order to include the project:

Properties -> Build Path -> Projects -> Add , add the project you want.

Comment: what after this how do i call an main method of that class in this project.